# Füllwörter im Deutschen (ähnlich wie "you know")

Tags: word-choice, idiomaticity

Wie würde man im Deutschen die englische Phrase "you know" (als ein Füllwort gemeint) ausdrücken? Gibt es einige andere Redemittel beim Zögern?

Comment: Similar question in English: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/what-is-the-german-equivalent-for-these-speech-fillers-from-english-umm-an

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt so einige.

- Weißt du/woaßt/weisch/weiße (und in verschiedenen anderen Dialekten/Akzenten)
- halt
- also
- eben
- …

Das unterscheidet sich kaum vom Englischen, wo es neben *you know* auch *like, see, you see* und viele mehr gibt.

Um »auf Situationen passende« Füllwörter zu lernen, solltest du am besten viel mit Muttersprachlern reden und ihnen viel zuhören, dann werden sie dir von selbst auffallen.

Comment: Jedenfalls ist das hier eine, ähm -- *du weißt schon*, brauchbare Antwort.

Answer (score 1):

Ergänzung zu Jans Liste:

- Nicht wahr (oft verkürzt zu *ne* oder ähnlich, abhängig von der Region)
- ja (mit ziemlich kurzem *a*)